# Microsoft Power Query M formula language to sql query conversion

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, jdbc, powerquery

I am working on a re-platforming project where we are re-writing existing code in java and angular 7, I am stuck at a place where I have to write SQL queries for set of 'Power Query M Language' queries that I need to execute against SQL Server.
One of the M language query is, we have queries much bigger than this and so many

```
    Source = Sql.Database("server,port", "DBNAME"),
    dbo_tbl_ProgramConfiguration = Source{[Schema="SCHEMA",Item="TABLE"]}[Data],
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.ExpandListColumn(Table.TransformColumns(<TABLE>, {{"Roles", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(";", QuoteStyle.None), let itemType = (type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true] in type {itemType}}}), "Roles"),
    #"Trimmed Text" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Split Column by Delimiter",{{"Roles", Text.Trim, type text}}),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Trimmed Text",{{"Roles", "Role"}}),
    #"Removed Other Columns - Keep Title, RolesId, NewColumn.Role" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Renamed Columns",{"Program", "Role"}),
    #"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Removed Other Columns - Keep Title, RolesId, NewColumn.Role",{"Role"},Roles,{"Role"},"Roles",JoinKind.Inner),
    #"Expanded Roles" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "Roles", {"Id"}, {"RolesId"}),
   #"Reordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Expanded Roles",{"Program", "Role", "RolesId"})
in
    #"Reordered Columns"
```

So I was looking for any transformational tool or any feature in Java/JDBC where this M Language queries can be converted to SQL or can directly be executed against SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly a full solution for your problem but some information that might help.

But you can try and get the SQL Query Power Query is executing.

If you are running this on Power BI, you can just go to the Power Query Editor window and for that query you can check the View native Query for the last step. If it is now greyed out, you are in luck. This will show you the query it runs to get the data with all the transformations applied. This happens due to Power Query Query Folding capabilities, where it will apply the transformations at the source if supported.

*Be aware some transformation or even the order the transformation were applied may stop folding from happening for all steps, those transformations will get applied locally.*

Not sure if you can access this directly within Excel's Power Query.

*But you can do a trace on your source and catch the query it runs.*

[image: View Native Query]

EDIT:

you can customize the query, your step in M should look something like this:

```
Sql.Database("YOURSERVERNAME", "Tailspintoys-us", [Query="select * from Sales"])
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the native query view is disabled for complex queries. I tried tracing the DB also but looks like the complex/nested queries are broken down into smaller queries and the data join is applied on the client side which is excel workbook. so not much useful for me. Is there other way to use M Language Power queries to directly execute against MS SQL server, or any Java plugin that can execute this.